# Access violation reading location in a destructor of a class

Tags: c++

I've built the Graph class, one constructor and one destructor. My problem is: when i compile this code, i get an error at this line `delete [] mat[i];`, the error is 'Access violation reading location 0xDDDDDDCD.' and i'm not sure what am i doing wrong. I mean i only delete the memory i dynamically alocated. 
Later edit: even if i use this instead of my method :

```
Graph(int nr_noduri) {


this->nr_noduri = nr_noduri;
    mat = new bool* [nr_noduri];
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
        mat[i] = new bool[nr_noduri];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nr_noduri; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

My code  is :

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class Graph {
    bool** mat;
    int nr_noduri;

public:
    Graph(int nr_noduri) {
        this->nr_noduri = nr_noduri;
        mat = (bool**)calloc(nr_noduri, sizeof(bool*));
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
            mat[i] = (bool*)calloc(nr_noduri, sizeof(bool));
        }
    }

    int size() {
        return nr_noduri;
    }

    void addArc(int v, int w) {
        if (v < nr_noduri && w < nr_noduri) {
            mat[v][w] = true;
        }
        else cout << "Not enough nodes !" << endl;
    }

    bool isArc(int v, int w) {
        return (mat[v][w] == true);

    }

    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
            cout << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < nr_noduri; j++) {
                cout << mat[i][j] << " ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    ~Graph() {
        //cout << nr_noduri;
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
            delete [] mat[i];
        }
        delete[] mat;
    }

    friend void dfs(Graph g, int v, bool vazut[]);
};

void dfs(Graph g, int v, bool vazut[]) {
    int w;
    vazut[v] = true;
    for (w = 0; w < g.size(); w++) {
        if (g.isArc(v, w) && !vazut[w]) {
            cout << v << "->" << w;
            dfs(g, w, vazut);
        }
    }
}


int main() {
    int nr_noduri;
    cin >> nr_noduri;
    Graph v(nr_noduri);
    v.print();
    v.addArc(1, 2);
    v.addArc(2, 5);
    cout << v.isArc(1, 2) << endl;
    v.print();
    bool vazut[100];
    dfs(v, 1, vazut);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you see a highly regular number like `0xDDDDDDCD`, the program is [probably trying to tell you something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values). 0xDDDDDDCD is probably 0xDDDDDDDD with an offset, and looking up 0xDDDDDDDD we find the program is likely trying to use memory that had previously been returned.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): You should familiarize yourself with [the Rule of Three and its friends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). You can't safely use a class like this without taking them into account.

Comment: `void dfs(Graph g, int v, bool vazut[])` -- You are passing `Graph` by value, and `Graph` does not have correct copy semantics.  The code as posted is not going to work until you implement the Rule of 3 (already mentioned).  No need to look further.

Comment: A simple [2 line main program](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481ad0921c4667d6) shows the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

`void dfs(Graph g, int v, bool vazut[])`

has the first parameter `g` passed by value, thus will be a temporary copy of the `Graph` that is passed in.  If `Graph` does not have correct copy semantics, then the call to `dfs` will cause undefined behavior.

The `Graph` contains a member `mat` that points to dynamically allocated memory.  In addition, `Graph` has a destructor that issues a `delete []` on this memory.  So when `Graph` is copied, that `mat` pointer is also copied.  You now have **two** `mat` pointers pointing to the same memory.  When the temporary goes out of scope, `delete []` will be issued on the `mat` pointer.

That is probably the reason why you are getting runtime issues -- the memory `mat` was pointing to has already been deleted, and you're deleting it again a second time.

To fix this issue you have two choices:

1. Pass `Graph` by reference to `dfs` instead of by value, or
2. Fix your `Graph` class to handle copies correctly.

For item 1:

`void dfs(Graph& g, int v, bool vazut[])`

that avoids the temporary copy from being made.

---

However, that to me is just a band-aid solution to avoid having to hit the copy bug (even though you should pass-by-reference anyway).

A better one is to make the `Graph` class safely copyable, meaning that copies can be made correctly, without a "double deletion" errors you're seeing now.

To do that, add the following functions to complete the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to allow copying to be performed correctly:

```
#include <algorithm>
//…
Graph(const Graph& rhs) : mat(nullptr), nr_noduri(rhs.nr_noduri)
{
    mat = new bool* [rhs.nr_noduri];
    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nr_noduri; i++) {
        mat[i] = new bool[rhs.nr_noduri];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rhs.nr_noduri; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rhs.nr_noduri; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = rhs.mat[i][j];
        }
    }
}

Graph& operator=(const Graph& rhs)
{
    if ( this != &rhs )
    {
        Graph temp(rhs);
        std::swap(temp.mat, mat);
        std::swap(temp.nr_noduri, nr_noduri);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Your class was lacking a user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator (which uses the [copy / swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)).

---

Another unrelated issue is the way you're building your 2D matrix.  You're using one of the worst methods, and that is to allocate pointers, then in a loop, allocate each row.

It not only is a bottleneck in terms of speed (calling the allocator for each row), it is not cache-friendly due to the rows being allocated in different parts of the heap, in addition to heap fragmentation, and if one of those calls to `new[]` within the loop fails, you have to rollback all of the successful calls to `new[]` if you don't want to leak memory.

See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943621/how-to-create-a-contiguous-2d-array-in-c/21944048#21944048) for a better method of creating a 2D array.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `delete` to deallocate memory that was allocated by `calloc` (or any of the `malloc` family of functions). Use `new` instead to allocate memory.

```
Graph(int nr_noduri) {
    this->nr_noduri = nr_noduri;
    mat = new bool*[nr_noduri];
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_noduri; i++) {
        mat[i] = new bool[nr_noduri];
    }
}
```

Better yet, use `std::vector<std::vector<bool>>` to hold the data.

```
class Graph {
   std::vector<std::vector<bool>> mat;

   Graph(int nr_noduri) : mat(nr_noduri, std::vector<bool>(nr_noduri) {}

   ...
};
```

Comment: Does it matter if they're calling C code whether to use new/delete vs. *alloc/free in their code?

Comment: @Mode77, no, it does not. Once memory is allocated, rest of the code can use the memory regardless of how it was allocated.

Comment: @RSahu ...although you might have to placement-new objects into that memory first.

Comment: even if i do it with new and then i initalize all the matrix with zeros, i still get that error when i deallocate memory, i really dont get it why

Comment: @ballow, when I commented out the call to `dfs` in `main`, the  problem went away. You are doing something in that function that causes undefined behavior. You'll have to step through that code in a debugger to figure out how to resolve it.